# Error in Python requests: ValueError

Tags: python, apache-drill

So I'm using the PyDrill to make an SQL query:

This is the relevant code:

```
 yelp_reviews = drill.query('''
  SELECT sum(case when t.attributes.Parking.garage='true' then 1 else 0 end) as garage,
  sum(case when t.attributes.Parking.street='true' then 1 else 0 end) as street,
  sum(case when t.attributes.Parking.validated='true' then 1 else 0 end) as validated,
  sum(case when t.attributes.Parking.valet='true' then 1 else 0 end) as valet,
  sum(case when t.attributes.Parking.lot='true' then 1 else 0 end) as lot FROM `mongo.274_BI`.`yelp_dataset`t
  where t.city=?
''','Las Vegas')
```

While executing this I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Timeout value connect was Las Vegas, but it must be an int or float.
```

I updated the requests using

```
pip install -U requests;
```

The error still persists though. Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

`drill.query` is expecting a timeout value for the second argument. You are passing in the string "Las Vegas" which is not a number (ie `int` or `float`).

According to the [documentation](https://pydrill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html#pydrill.client.PyDrill.query) `query` accepts two parameters `sql` and `timeout`. Your SQL should be passed in as the first argument and a timeout should be passed in as the optional second parameter.

After looking at it more thoroughly, you want "Las Vegas" to be safely interpolated into the sql. It seems like PyDrill doesn't support this. The solution would be to just add "Las Vegas" to the actual query which will work as long as the sql doesn't come from an untrusted source. If it does, I would recommend opening an issue with PyDrill as this should be supported IMO.